# Is there a way to set property value format requirements based on a condition of the property name?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a simple JSON schema:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

It requires that `name` property is a string. This schema does not restrict additional properties, e.g.

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  url: 'http://foo'/
}
```

The latter is a valid input.

Is there a way to set a property value format requirement based on a conditional property name match?, e.g. any property that contains `url` string in it must correspond to the following schema:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "format": "url"
}
```

Therefore, an input:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  location_url: 'not-a-valid-url'
}
```

would cause an error because `location_url` does not contain a valid URL?

I'd imagine, a schema for something like this would look like:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "matchProperties": {
    "/url/i": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "url"
    }
  }
  "type": "object"
}
```

where `matchProperties` is a keyword I made up.

Comment: There is a standard keyword called [patternProperties](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#patternproperties) that does exactly that

Comment: How did I overlook that! :-) Please add this one-liner as an answer.

Comment: You may also use "format":"uri". http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7,  but you have to check that your validator implements this format.